# order and order_lines tables - duplicate data or use versioning?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

Is it bad to duplicate names and prices into order_lines tables (references from product and options tables)?

I've have checked a few popular ecommerce open sources PHP scripts and it does it.

Assume the following tables (quick example):

`product` table:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| product_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`options` table: (a product can have 1 or more options, eg: small, large, x-large, etc)

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| option_id  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name       | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price      | decimal(6,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Company will be getting about 5000 new orders daily, I am looking for a reasonable way how to design order, order_line tables?  Do you duplicate names and prices into order_lines table? Hundreds of prices will be changed every few month from the `options` table.

I have read about versioning (Type 2), im not sure how it actually work, from what I can understand I can add `version_id` field in the `product`, `options` and order_line tables.  Whatever the MAX version_id is, its mean the latest version.  It seem much easier than using StartDate and EndDate design.

I am looking for the design methodology that can be done quick and reasonable. Not too complicated design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `options` table is not large (in row size, not number of rows) so storing the name multiple times shouldn't be a problem. However, if you want to ensure the same string is used for all "Large" options then extracting the strings to a lookup table will help.

As a side note, you may want to reconsider your primary key for this table as using an auto increment field allows for a product to have the same option applied more than once.

Having a lookup table for the names would require versioning as changes to the table have an effect on historical rows. You can use version numbers or date ranges, whichever is easier for you, although the use of dates does also let you know when the change to an option occurred.

Dates may be a little easier to use as you can use triggers to update the table, writing the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in to the table without needing to know the previous version number. Using version number requires a loop up before update.

You might find it useful to have a look at "Developing Time Oriented Databases" by Richard Snodgrass, available free h=from here: [http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/%7Erts/publications.html)

**EDIT:** A table with version information usually has a date/time field holding the 'valid_from' date for that row. New rows will have this automatically filled with 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' so you know which is the most recent row. Other methods use two fields to record the start and end time when the row was valid. Using the two fields makes the queries easier as you can do 'SELECT ... WHERE point_in_time BETWEEN start_date AND end_date'

Comment: `options` table will be very large (over 100,000 rows and with random names (only a few hundred are duplicates). I am little concern about using dates for versioning - is it 100% accurate look up?  I also have a tables called `extras` that are linked with `options`. Eg: An Option can have couple of extras with it.  Let say I change the the of `product.name` (fix spelling) - what will happen option table and extras table that are linked to?

Comment: @user791022 - I'm not sure of the resolution of the time part of MySQL date type, I know that SQL Server improved the data type to be mroe accurate but it depends on how fast you expect changes to be happening to the options. When performing the lookup you just want to know the current version so a `... WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN start_version_date AND end_version_date` should suffice.

Comment: Cool, I understand I think.  Whenever a record is updated (eg: product.name changed) - what will happen to existing records? `product.id` are related `options.product_id` and then options table related to `extra.option_id`

Comment: @user791022 - I've added some more information to my answer but I do recommend you read the Snodrass book. It's very good and free!

Comment: See my new question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699351/tables-versioning-historical-tables-and-order-tables-relationship