# Tables versioning (historical tables) and Order tables relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

If I add a new product in the `products` table or change the data - it will automatically add into `products_history`. This is done by trigger.

When customer placed the order, there is no need to duplicate the name of product in the `order_products` table.

To get the pruduct name and price from the `order_products` table - you will query from the `products_history` table not the `products` table

Note: I am showing simple tables for demonstration.

See the following tables and the result:

```
mysql> select * from products;
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
| id | name       | price | timestamp           |
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | Product 63 |  2.00 | 2011-10-08 18:55:53 |
|  2 | Product 42 |  3.00 | 2011-10-08 18:55:44 |
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+

mysql> select * from products_history;
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
| id | name       | price | timestamp           |
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | Product 23 |  2.00 | 2011-10-08 18:55:44 |
|  2 | Product 42 |  3.00 | 2011-10-08 18:55:44 |
|  1 | Product 63 |  2.00 | 2011-10-08 18:55:53 |
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
```

**The orders tables:**

```
mysql> select * from `order`;
+----+-------------+
| id | total_price |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |     9999.00 |
+----+-------------+

mysql> select * from order_products;
+----+----------+------------+---------------------+
| id | order_id | product_id | product_timestamp   |
+----+----------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 |        1 |          2 | 2011-10-08 18:55:44 |
|  2 |        1 |          1 | 2011-10-08 18:55:53 |
+----+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

To get the product name and prices from the orders table:

```
SELECT order.total_price, products_history. * FROM  `order` 
   LEFT JOIN order_products ON order_products.order_id = order.id
   LEFT JOIN products_history ON products_history.id = order_products.product_id
             AND products_history.timestamp = order_products.product_timestamp
WHERE order.id =1
```

**Result**:

```
+-------------+------+------------+-------+---------------------+
| total_price | id   | name       | price | timestamp           |
+-------------+------+------------+-------+---------------------+
|     9999.00 |    2 | Product 42 |  3.00 | 2011-10-08 18:55:44 |
|     9999.00 |    1 | Product 63 |  2.00 | 2011-10-08 18:55:53 |
+-------------+------+------------+-------+---------------------+
```

It seem to work fine.

Is there any major flaw in this design or what I could have done differently?

---

Second question about Extras...  A product can have extras or without extras. Do I need to versioned for `extra_group` table? I have only versioned for the `extra` table.

See the following tables:

```
mysql> select * from extra_group;
+----+------------------+
| id | name             |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | Extras Group One |
+----+------------------+

mysql> select * from extras;
+----+---------+-------+---------------------+
| id | name    | price | timestamp           |
+----+---------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | Extra 1 |  0.30 | 2011-10-08 18:57:55 |
|  2 | Extra 2 |  2.31 | 2011-10-08 18:58:10 |
+----+---------+-------+---------------------+

mysql> select * from extras_history;
+----+---------+-------+---------------------+
| id | name    | price | timestamp           |
+----+---------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | Extra 1 |  0.30 | 2011-10-08 18:57:55 |
|  2 | Extra 2 |  2.30 | 2011-10-08 18:57:55 |
|  2 | Extra 2 |  2.31 | 2011-10-08 18:58:10 |
+----+---------+-------+---------------------+


mysql> select * from products_extras;
+----+------------+----------------+
| id | product_id | extra_group_id |
+----+------------+----------------+
|  1 |          2 |              1 |
+----+------------+----------------+
//This mean Product ID 2 have extras from  extra_group_id = 1
```

**Order table for extras:**

```
mysql> select * from order_products_extras;
+-------------------+----------+---------------------+
| order_products_id | extra_id | extra_timestamp     |
+-------------------+----------+---------------------+
|                 1 |        1 | 2011-10-08 18:57:55 |
|                 1 |        2 | 2011-10-08 18:58:10 |
+-------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

//Customer selected extra_id 1 and 2 from product_id 1

Use similar query like above to get the extra name and price from the `extras_history` table

**Triggers**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `extras-afterinsert` AFTER INSERT ON `extras`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `extras_history` VALUES (NEW.`id`, NEW.`name`, NEW.`price`, NEW.`timestamp`);
END
|
CREATE TRIGGER `extras-afterupdate` AFTER UPDATE ON `extras`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `extras_history` VALUES (NEW.`id`, NEW.`name`, NEW.`price`, NEW.`timestamp`);
END
```

And similar for the `products_history` table.

Am I wasting my time using historical tables, should I just duplicate names/prices into `order_products` and `order_products_extras` tables ?

Note: There will be over 100,000 rows in the procucts and extras tables.. and over 1000 orders a day.

Comment: You should only denormalize when slowness sets in, not before. Because you are doing equi-joins on the historical data I don't think slowness will be a problem so your approach looks fine to me.

Comment: You have a total_price value of 9999.00, but the items total only 5.00. That sure *looks* like a flaw.

Comment: @Catcall - lol... it was a quick example of total_price.. yes thats wrong.. What do you think of this Tables versioning?

Answer (score 0):

One danger with only recording a single timestamp is that it's hard to determine what the latest entry is for a given order.  You have to use a subselect or a function.  I'd recommending having start_timestamp and finish_timestamp, with the latter being NULL for the latest entry.  When an entry becomes history, it gets its finish_timestamp filled in.  There are other ways to deal with this problem, I'm sure, but this seems to me to be the most straightforward.

Comment: If there is a NULL in a history table and I insert a new/change data in the primary table - how does the NULL get updated? Is that done by trigger or use PHP? When Null has been updated.. then insert a new row?

Comment: @user791022: yes, you'd either have to use a trigger, or do it manually in code (or in a stored procedure, if you're into that kind of thing).  I implied it's not perfect, but it's still easier than having to have complicated queries to retrieve the latest entry.

Comment: One thing that came to my mind that having a single timestamp - you still can find out which are the latest entry by using MAX function. Eg: `SELECT MAX(timestamp) AS max_date FROM  products_history where id = '5'`

Comment: @user791022: to find the latest entry for a single order, you can do that.  Otherwise, all that gets you is the latest timestamp.  You can't, for example, do a SELECT id GROUP BY order_id HAVING MAX(timestamp) to find the latest entries for a set of orders and get a meaningful result.

Answer (score 0):

I really couldn't understand what you are trying to achieve with history tables. If the products price changes rapidly and you want to save the products base price at that current time why not put it into order_product ?

```
orders :
order_id / created_at / status (PK : order_id)

order_products : 
order_id / product_id / quantity /  product_price (PK : order_id, product_id)
```

this way you wouldn't have to join product_history every single time. you can do same denormalization for extras aswell.

P.S : try not to use reserved words like "order" in table / column names, it can introduce bugs.

Comment: Products price will be changed often, maybe about 100 new prices every month.

Comment: and you are interested at price from the exact time they are ordered right ? then denormalize order_products and put a price instead of timestamp, since you are using that timestamp only to retrieve price itself as far as I see.

Comment: Yes I will put the price in the `order_products` table. What about the product name? Would you recommend to lookup from history table via timestamp or denormalize order_products with product name

Comment: its not a big problem to join order_products with products table since it would join from primary index (product_id).

Comment: Are you referring history product table? The product name often changed slightly

Comment: well if you need the old names (instead of new names) then ofcourse its better to put it in order_products aswell. I thought you might want to see the new names.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4113/discussion-between-user791022-and-frail)